# Send multiple variable with PHP AJAX GET onclick of a button

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have two dynamically loaded dropdowns: one containing golf course holes information and another holding users- together the information will be used to generate a scorecard.

When the course is selected and a user is selected I want to click a button and then this will generate the scorecard.

Below is the code for the 'course' dropdown

```
<?php
    $db_host = 'localhost';
    $db_user = 'root';
    $db_pass = '';
    $db_name = '';

    $con = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass, $db_name);
    if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }   


    $sql = "SELECT courseID, name FROM courses";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $courses[] = '<option       value="'.$row['courseID'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
    } 
     ?>
```

Below is the code for the 'user' dropdown

```
<?php


    $db_host = 'localhost';
    $db_user = 'root';
    $db_pass = '';
    $db_name = '';

    $con = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass, $db_name);
    if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }   


    $sql = "SELECT userID, forename, surname FROM user";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $users[] = '<option value="'.$row['userID'].'">'.$row['forename'].' '.$row['surname'].'</option>';
    }

     ?>
```

Below is the HTML code for the dropdowns

```
<form>
<select id="selectCourse" onchange="showCourse(this.value)"> 
  <option value = "">Select Course</option>
  <?php foreach($courses as $c){
    echo $c;
}?>
</select>

<select id="selectUser" >
    <option value = "">Select User</option>
    <?php foreach($users as $u){
        echo $u;
    } ?>
    </select>

<button type="button" >Click me</button>
</form>
```

At the moment I have code that uses the 'onchange' to load the first part of the scorecard which contains the hole information about that course. I am having problems changing this to the click of the button and also consider another variable from the user dropdown.

The below code is taken from W3Schools which loaded the hole information correctly based on 'onchange'.

```
   <script>
function showCourse(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","generateSC.php?cValue="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
```

The below code shows the first half of the scorecard being generated from the selection of the first dropdown.

```
    <?php
$cValue = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['cValue']);



$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = '';
$db_name = '';

$con = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_name);
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

$sql="SELECT DISTINCT holeNumber, strokeIndex, par FROM holes WHERE courseID= '".$cValue."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));


echo '<div class="scorecardTable">
<table>
<tr>
<th>HoleNumber</th>
<th>Par</th>
<th>Stroke Index</th>
<th>Score</th>
<th>Points</th>
</tr>';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['holeNumber'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['par'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['strokeIndex'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td> <input required type=text /></td>";
    echo "<td> </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

What I am looking to know is can I pass two variables through at this point below:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","generateSC.php?cValue="+str,true);
```

and if so how would I get the second variable.

**EDIT**

```
 <script>
function showCourse(course, user) {

    var user = document.getElementById('selectUser').value;
    var course = document.getElementById('selectCourse').value;

    if (user || course == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","generateSC.php?course="+course+"&user="+user,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
```

I've updated what I have above... the problem now is how do i get the button to work with the two variables?

```
                 <form>
<select id="selectCourse"> 
  <option value = "">Select Course</option>
  <?php foreach($courses as $c){
    echo $c;
}?>
</select>

<select id="selectUser" >
    <option value = "">Select User</option>
    <?php foreach($users as $u){
        echo $u;
    } ?>
    </select>

<button type="button" >Click me</button>
</form>
```

Comment: As easy as `"generateSC.php?cValue="+str+"&whatever="+whatelse`

Comment: You get the second variable in PHP using `$_GET["whatever"]`

Comment: In Javascript you can get the second drop down value using `whatelse = document.getElementById("selectUser").value`

Comment: Thanks for the help, appreciate it

Comment: Do you have any idea what I would do to the button to load the generateSC page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fetch the values from both dropdowns and concatinate the URL:

```
var user = document.getElementById('selectUser').value;
var course = document.getElementById('selectCourse').value;
xmlhttp.open("GET","generateSC.php?cValue="+course+"&user="+user,true);
```

Then your generateSC php script will of course have to fetch the value from the user parameter and work with that as well.

`$_GET['user']` will fetch the value from the user parameter.

Comment: Made those adjustments thanks, would you have any idea what I do with the button - is it a case of removing the "onChange" from the first dropdown and referencing the "generateSC" on click of the button?

Comment: Yes, that's basically what you need to to.  Unless you need to filter the user list or something when a course is selected from the course dropdown.

Comment: no there is no filter needed, the two aren't linked in any way. I need the user table to access each players handicap for the scorecard. Thanks for the help appreciate it